# Promotional rules in Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, promotions

I'm trying to get a promotional rule setup in Magento where if a user orders any items and the subtotal is between $100 and $200 they get 10% off. If it's more than $200, there is no discount and if it's less than $100 there is no discount either.

Right now I have it set to say if all of these conditions are true:

Subtotal is greater than $100

Subtotal is less than $200

But it's not applying the discount and I'm not sure why.

Here's a screen shot of what I have in the Conditions:

[image]

And here's what I have in the Actions section:

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with your logic, lets see your code.  "it's not working" is not a valid question.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott - Ummm, I don't have any code. It's within the Promotion setting in Magento. I added a screenshot to possibly illustrate what I am doing.

Comment: What do you have in the actions section?

Comment: Do you have other rules with "Stop Further Rules Processing"=true option?

Comment: Shouldn't your second rule be 'equal or less than $200'?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott - I've updated my post with a screen shot of the actions section

Comment: @KevinDTimm - I've tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Anthony - I don't believe so.

Comment: have you tried to refresh all the caches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all of the rules from your Conditions tab since you are trying to apply this to individual products.

On the Actions tab, do the following:

[image: Actions Tab]

This will discount all items in the cart by 10% with the row total between $100 - $200.

Comment: SHABOOM! That was it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Also I noticed you were using `$` in the amount (which actually might of been the culprit).  Make sure you are using just numeric values for promotions (no currency denotations).